# React Native, Javascript : Simple function to return all dates between two dates, gives different result on simulator and real-life device

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, date, react-native

I have a simple function, when returns all dates between two dates.

See the code :

```js
events(s, e){
    let between = [];
    let currentDate = new Date(s);
    let end = new Date(e);
    while (currentDate <= end) {
      let dum = new Date(currentDate);
      let dummy = moment(dum).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      between.push(dummy);
      currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return(between);
  }
```

I'm using it in my react native app. there is one problem which happens only when I give start and end dates as 2016-10-22 and 2016-10-30.

In this particular case, when i run it in iOS simulator, the return array's length is 9. the array includes the start date and end date and all dates between.

I run the exact same app, exact same function and parameters, app in iPhone returns different results (only in this particular case while start and end dates are 2016-10-22 and 2016-10-30)

In iPhone, array's length is 8, and it's not including the last date.

Is there any logical problem in my function?

Comment: Why don't you use momentjs for all date operations?

Comment: let me try it. Thanks for your comment.